# Undefined index text input php?

Tags: php, mysql, file, input, dao

i want get text input value from php web file for save values to database, but text input not work with php file. And show this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: txtUsername in C:/...... line 7
>   Notice: Undefined index: txtPassword in C:/...... line 8

my html:

```
<form  action="../Controller/LoginController.php">
    <input type="text" id="txtUsername" />
    <input type="text" id="txtPassword"  />
    <input type="submit" name="btnLogin" value="login" />
</form>
```

my php file:

```
$strUsername = $_POST["txtUsername"];  //line 7
$strPassword = $_POST["txtPassword"];  //line 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Form input ID can't be used for getting the value. You need to set the `name` attribute.

Like that:

```html
<input type="text" name="txtUsername" /> // Notice the name attribute
```

You can then get the value normally.

```php
$strUsername = $_POST["txtUsername"];
```

Comment: Hey, downvoter, care to explain the reason of downvoting?

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing it via `$_POST` in the PHP code, but not specifically passing it via `POST` in your HTML.

You also need to specify the NAME parameter, since that's what gets referenced by PHP, not ID

Try this:

```
<form action="../Controller/LoginController.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="txtUsername" name="txtUsername" />
    <input type="text" id="txtPassword" name="txtPassword"  />
    <input type="submit" name="btnLogin" value="login" />
</form>
```